# ubuntu 15.04 installer cannot find my hard disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 15.04, gparted

I'm trying to install ubuntu 15.04 beside windows 10, but installer can't find my hard drive,

here is the gparted output:

[image: gparted]

but I get this on installer:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try running my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) on the disk. If it complains about leftover GPT data, let FixParts delete it. If not, type `p` at the main FixParts menu to verify that the partitions look OK, and if they do, type `w` to save FixParts' view of your partitions.

Comment: @RodSmith awesome! please make it as answer so I can mark it as best answer

Comment: **The following is @HonkTonkMan 's comment.**


I´m with the same problem! Did you
fixed it with FixParts? Does dual-boot
works right now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear where you want Ubuntu installing. ie what partition.
I assume you want to install ubuntu over your Fedora install on sda5, as there's no room elsewhere.
If that's the case try using gparted to format sda5 to ext4. 
It should then be seen by the installer.

Comment: It is not even finding my hard disk